# Google Place Autocomplete API doesn't return the results in the correct language

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, localization, javascript

I'm using the same code from the documentation page https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform
and I also set the &language=en while loading the script.

When I search for München the city field is populated with Munich, but when I search for an address in München (for example: Residenzstraße, Munich, Germany) the city field is populated with München instead of Munich.

[image]

[image]

It seems that `autocomplete.getPlace()` doesn't take into consideration the language specified while loading the script.

The issue is reproducible also on the documentation link provided.

How can I specify that I always want the results in english?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think places is trying its best to do the translation, if I set the lang to JP, it would give me a result where the country is in Japanese. I would say that this address, is the best Japanese language localized address the places API can give.
[image: Japanese]

More to support this is, when we put the Narita International Airport's address (in Japanese) into the box, it would return an English address.
[image: English-Narita]

so.. if there really are problems, that would be the lack of information in Google Maps database, or the translations.

and so I would say Google Place Autocomplete API does try to return the results in the correct language...

A work around would be to get the geolocation and get the address from openstreet map API... like this:

http://kylelam.github.io/SO/autoCompleteWithOpenStreetMap.html

https://github.com/kylelam/kylelam.github.io/blob/master/SO/autoCompleteWithOpenStreetMap.html

Comment: I don't think it's a problem with the translations, because sometime it will return München and sometime Munich even if the language is set to english. The problem is that I want to have only one of them all the time, otherwise I will need to do the mapping by myself.

Comment: My point is, for the second example, if I set the location to Japanese, it is going to give me all Japanese output. So the fact that google gave me a Japanese result in the first image, where I set my language to Japanese, means the country code is effective and that's the limit of the Google map.  One work around could be using another map services:p I posted the code in my original answer.

Comment: Thanks! I've used your idea but instead of using another map service I had trigger a second geocoding call only with "City, Country" and in this case I got the city name in english. I really hope there is another solution which uses only a geocoding call and returns all the fields translated.

Comment: yea, I also filed a bug in the issue tracker, hopefully they will fix it soon.

Comment: can you please let me know the url of your reported bug?

Comment: Should be this one, I just copy and paste from here... https://code.google.com/p/googlebugs/issues/detail?id=682&thanks=682&ts=1426797026

Comment: I found a bug with this issue reported in January https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7504&q=language&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal

Comment: omg.. my bad I didn't see it let me mark it as duplicate OR may be I should just leave it alone since they are actually 2 different product (even the root cause might be the same)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try specify the language on your url ?

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Vict&types=geocode&**language=en**

Answer (score 0):

A bug is reported with this issue 
https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7504&q=language&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal